# Avg function from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new at SQL, I looking to get an AVG function from two queries (join to one query by groups).

my query template.

```
WITH group1 AS (
SELECT 
          ID AS ID
         ,date AS date
         ,TYPE AS TYPE
         ,GROUP_M AS GROUP_M
         ,Value AS Value
         ,AVG (NULLIF( Value , 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY  TYPE  ) AS TYPE_AVG
FROM
(
SELECT  
          a4.id AS ID
         ,a0.data AS date
         ,GET_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ( a12.attributes , Upper('TYPE'), '=') AS TYPE
         ,GET_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE ( a12.attributes , Upper('GROUP_M'), '=') AS GROUP_M
         ,a4.value AS Value
         ,a12.attributes AS attributes
FROM 
    SESSION a2
LEFT JOIN P_id a0 ON a0.id = a2.id
INNER JOIN P_SET a3 ON a3.id = a2.id 
WHERE
              a2.name = 'REVIEW' 
 AND      a2.test_name = '4M' 

 AND      a0.data >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7 

)
),
group2 AS (
 SELECT 

         ,wch.id AS E_id
         ,e.entity AS Entity
FROM 
       F_machine wch
INNER JOIN F_Entity e ON e.entity = wch.entity 
INNER JOIN F_Run_card lrc ON lrc.lotoperkey = wch.lotoperkey
INNER JOIN F_Route r ON r.route=lrc.route AND r.facility = lrc.facility AND r.latest_version = 'Y'
WHERE
              e.entity Like 'E%' 
 AND      e.entity Is Not Null  
 AND      wch.end_time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 14 
)
SELECT *
  FROM group1
  JOIN group2 ON group1.id = group2.E_id
;
```

my end goal is to have one more column - average of value by machine and type

`AVG (NULLIF( {value} , 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY  {machine} ,  {TYPE}  )`

thanks and hope everything is clear :)

Comment: Hello please add your DBMS https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

Comment: Can you please provide some sample records from each table, and specify what you want the result to be? As posted, the question is not clear.

Comment: I tagged "SQL" if I understand it correctly

Comment: @DanielE. is referring to the specific flavor of SQL that you're using (SQL Server/T-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: not really sure... I'm using Bi4 if it helps

Comment: I edit my Q. scrubbed a bit, from IP

Comment: `SQL` is just a common language used by all rdbms vendors.  Each vendor has their own variation of functions and/or syntax.  It's useless if someone gave you solution in Oracle, but you use MySQL.

Comment: So you don't even know which dbms you are using?

Comment: What I'm looking for is samples of the tables that you're querying (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314087/sql-merging-rows-if-date-connects) post). Your query by itself is not of much use in answering these sorts of questions.